# Is it possible to make countries clickable on a map?

Tags: html, css, image, border

Say a webpage renders a realistic world map, so the countries have jagged borders. To my knowledge, it would be next to impossible to draw divs that exactly match the country shapes using common CSS.

Is it possible to make the individual countries clickable, exactly following the borders?
[image: map]

Answer (score 1):

For this you would use the HTML <map> element. This essentially requires that you have a static image, because you have to specify each point in an area.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

A map element has the map name and is comprised of area child elements.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

For arbitrarily shaped area, you would use shape="poly" and put in the x- and y- coordinates for each point.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_area_coords.asp

It is also possible to use what's known as a server-side image map, though these have fallen out of fashion. These are more complicated, require a scripting language on the backend, and are considered less accessible than client-side maps. They were popular in the early days of the web.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [this](https://www.image-map.net/) but once you doit you cant resize the image or the map wont fit properly.